# Statistics multimode to get list of most common values

Tags: python

I use Python 3.9.5. Seems like attribute is not available in this version of python and i have to use that python version. Is there any other approach to show elements in the way that attribute gives?

**Error:**

```
Execution failed.
AttributeError : module 'statistics' has no attribute 'multimode'
```

**Code:**

```
import statistics

..
values = statistics.multimode(vars))      #one or more
valuesCount = len(statistics.multimode(vars)) #count of them
..
```

Answer (score 0):

`multimode` is [available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) since 3.8.  So I guess you just think you use version 3.9.5 but you actually use a version < 3.8. Print the python version and see what you are actually using.

Comment: maybe i am using something on the web the compiler. Is there any other way to count the same that attribute of statistics make? I mean some other way around besides statistics.

Comment: @Henry - so what version of python you are really using?

Comment: on webpage it says Python3 (3.9.5)

Comment: Print the version as part of the script